# IKImageBrowserView example?

Tags: ios, swift, ikimagebrowserview, imagekit, ikimageview

Are there any examples how to use IKImageBrowserView in **Swift**? So far I think it works a bit like the implementation of an UITableView on iOS. It needs a method to tell it how  much items it should display and another method returning those items at a specific index and I have to set the datasource and the delegate of IKImageBrowserView (Hope this is correct). 
But what kind object do I have to return in the itemAtIndex method?

```
override func numberOfItemsInImageBrowser(aBrowser: IKImageBrowserView!) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

override func imageBrowser(aBrowser: IKImageBrowserView!, itemAtIndex index: Int) -> AnyObject! {
    return images[index]
}
```

I've set my ViewController class as the datasource of IKImageBrowserView but the above methods are never called. Has anybody an example? Thanks.